# Creación de vistas con UNION

Tags: mysql

Hola tengo 3 tablas y quiero crear una vista con las union de las 3 pero me arroja error cía do quiero hacerlo. Las tablas son:

- Tabla1 con los campos Dni, cargo, escuelacapital
- Tabla1 con los campos Dni, cargo, escuelaprovincia
- Tabla3 con los campos Dni, cargo, escuelaespecial

Mi query es

```
Create view docente 
As
(select Dni as Dni, cargo as cargo, escuelacapital as 
escuela from Tabla1 
Union
select Dni as Dni, cargo as cargo, escuelaprovincia as 
escuela from Tabla2
Union
select Dni as Dni, cargo as cargo, escuelaespecial as 
escuela from Tabla3
) ;
```

En mysql 5.0
Pero arroja un error en la línea del primer unión

Comment: Pon el error que arroja para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Replique la estructura de tu base y pude replicar el error. es solo un error de sintaxis quita los paréntesis.

```
CREATE VIEW docente1 AS
    SELECT 
        Dni AS Dni, cargo AS cargo, escuelacapital AS escuela
    FROM
        Tabla1 
    UNION SELECT 
        Dni AS Dni, cargo AS cargo, escuelaprovincia AS escuela
    FROM
         Tabla2 
     UNION SELECT 
         Dni AS Dni, cargo AS cargo, escuelaespecial AS escuela
    FROM
         Tabla3;
```